# Java's BigDecimal setScale

Tags: java, bigdecimal

Thanks for any advice.

Why is this:

```
import java.math.*;

public class bdt {

    public static void main (String [] args) {

        BigDecimal a = new BigDecimal ("1.0");
        BigDecimal b = new BigDecimal ("3.0");
        BigDecimal c = new BigDecimal ("0.0");

        c = a.divide (b,MathContext.DECIMAL128);
        c.setScale (2,RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
        System.out.println (a.toString ());
        System.out.println (b.toString ());
        System.out.println (c);

    }

}
```

yielding this:

```
1.0
3.0
0.3333333333333333333333333333
```

instead of:

```
1.0
3.0
0.33
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `BigDecimal` is *immutable* you have to assign the result of the call to [`setScale()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#setScale%28int,%20java.math.RoundingMode%29) to `c`,

```
c = c.setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
```

the linked Javadoc says (in part) *Returns a `BigDecimal` whose scale is the specified value*.

**tl;dr** 
It doesn't modify `c` in place.

Comment: In fact, `BigDecimal` instances are immutable

Comment: Thanks.  Now I feel stupid, because I've avoided this error in other method calls.  But, I'm learning.  Thanks again.